# Realistic wood creases

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-printing

I want to reproduce the shield on this picture :

[image: Base model]

I made most of the shield, which looks pretty good with some bevel & subdivision modifiers. Here is my base mesh :

[image: shield mesh]

I just cannot find a way to create the wood creases on it.

It seems that I have to work on the mesh with the subdivision modifier applied to avoid creases to be rounded ?

I've tried using the crease sculpt mode but I can't find a way to get "clean" creases as on the model, it always create "noisy" shapes around and deform my base shield shape.

I've also tried to use the knife to form the crease shape, it kind of works if I didn't apply the subdivision modifier before, but creases are in that case too smooth.

If the modifier is applied before, my mesh is a mess and I can't use the knife properly.

What I would like to do is to **add creases on my shield but keep the same shape and curve**.

Finally, I wonder if there is a way to use "grab" to move a crease (eg previously created through the knife) without deforming the shield curve ?

Thank you very much !

Base mesh blend file :

[image]

Comment: If you want to create real creases, sculpt is probably the easiest way to do it, I'm not sure why you failed with sculpt. Also you could use a texture for your sculpt brush

Comment: Another way would be to fake the wood with a normal map, but I suppose that it's not what you want

Comment: Even though it's quite toony.. I think there's a reason the shield in your reference is curved in only one dimension. 1. It could conceivably be made of planks in RL 2. It's therefore easier to sculpt / cut planks as a model.

Comment: Vertex crease is a great new feature in blender 3.1 and I think it might be helpful for you. If you haven't heard about it yet, I suggest you watch this 1 min video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQuBNb1E5Wg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two ways I'd go about this include one that you already tried: sculpting. Let me offer a few suggestions in case any help you:

First, duplicate your model. Work on a high poly copy of it (we'll discuss how to increase the resolution in the next suggestion: don't use **Subdivision modifiers**)

Use **Dyntopo** and/or **Remesh** (found at the top-right of the Sculpting UI:

[image]

**Remesh** will cut extra geometry into your shape using a voxel grid of a resolution you define when you go into the menu: the lower the number, the higher the detail level.

**Dyntopo** is fun! it dynamically adds extra detail (at a rate which you can, again, define) while you sculpt. Areas you've sculpted over will become denser (or less dense) with vertices while you go.

With this extra detail, you should be at your liberty to study the material you want to mimic and cut in your wooden detailing.

As Moonboots said in the comments, you could use a texture with your sculpting brush to help you stamp detail onto your surface.

The other suggestion (which Moonboots beat me to with their comment sent while I was typing :P) is to use a texture to add the details in. If you find a wooden texture you like online, it'll probably come with a **normal** and/or **displacement** map which can do the same thing, but using the object's material as opposed to helping you change its geometry.

If you're using a displacement map, fair warning: That (to my knowledge, please correct me if anyone knows better) only works in Cycles, and you have to make sure it's enabled in the material settings or it won't work:

[image]

Edit:
A third suggestion (thanks, Moonboots!) is to use the **Multiresolution** modifier. This essentially streamlines the process of keeping a low-poly mesh while working on a high poly mesh to sculpt with.

I'm not as familiar with it myself, but you can use it to set your subdivision level, method (simple or linear (smooth)), then sculpt in high-poly without losing your low-poly mesh underneath. You can then also use the modifier to bake your normal map from the high-poly sculpt. Learn more here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/multiresolution.html

Comment: another solution you could suggest is the Multires modifier

Comment: Note that it is common to do this to a copy of the shield; keeping the low poly version; sculpt the copy and then use the copy to bake maps that can be used to 'fake' the detail on the low poly version.

Comment: Thank you ! This is definitely better with dyntopo enabled, but I need like 250 resolution with constant detail to get "clean" creases. Does that make sense, or am I missing something ? Also, when I sculpt on the main face of the shield, it deforms other contours. Is there a way to sculpt only on the main face without moving its edges ? Thank you !

Comment: @louiscoquio, I believe you can use masking to choose which bits of the mesh get affected by your sculpting. Learn more here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/sculpt_paint/sculpting/hide_mask.html

Comment: I then probably need the multires modifier in order to hide edges, because with the subdivision modifier applied my mesh has too many vertices to select them appropriately and hide them. Thank you again !